# Winver command won't be executed in CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I'm using the CMD quite often and after Windows Updates I usually check with the Winver command what version I'm now on. Interestingly, I can't execute this command anymore when I start a new CMD instance with Win.Key + R because it tells me there is no such command. When I open up an admin CMD everything works fine. This issue also applies to the PowerShell. I've checked on some Windows 10 virtual machines and some other Windows 10 PCs to see if it has been a general change, but it seems the problem just affects my PC.

Does someone have any advice?

Comment: Not related, but since you're already using `Win+R`, you can type `winver` in the run box directly instead of launching cmd, then typing it.

Answer (score 0):

Start it again in as admin.  While it is displayed, right-click on the taskbar button and then right-click again on the "Version Reporter Applet" option and select properties.

From there you should be able to see where the winver.exe is located.  On my machine, it's in C:\Windows\System32 but it might be different for you.  It's likely that the non-admin level command prompt is not using the same path as the admin-level one.

Check your path for both scenarios.  Copy the winver.exe to a folder in the non-admin's path.  You might want to actually manually try to run the winver.exe from the non-admin command prompt first manually to make sure it's not a permissions issue instead, but I would think that you would have gotten a different message had that been the case.

Comment: The path seems to be ok. What strikes me is that I can't even run the help or tasklist command in a CMD instance that has been started with Win.Key + R.

Comment: What if you hard-code the path in your command, or change to the folder first, bypassing the path completely?  Does it still say bad command or filename or file not found?

Comment: When I use the complete path to the Winver command (C:\Windows\System32\winver.exe) it works fine. It also works for help and tasklist.

Comment: I've checked the system variables and found out that the path variable of my account (the PCs only and admin account) uses following path: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps. Should I just copy the system path variable to my users path variable? And by the way, is %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp the correct path of both the TMP and TEMP variable or is it wrong too?

Comment: You definitely want at least the system32 folder included in both paths.  The TMP and TEMP are generally used by applications but are not required, to the best of my knowledge.  Make a backup copy of your existing PATH in a notepad file or something, and then copy your admin PATH to the user one.  It's best to "merge" them but if it's a long path that might be difficult.